# Forwarding emails sent to noreply to proper recipient?

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this with MS Exchange 2010?

Basically I'm looking to send emails from several accounts with "sender" listed as noreply@whatever.com and if someone replies back to that email it'll automatically get forwarded to the proper recipient (i.e. the original sender).

I don't even know where to start with this. I was thinking there might be some way to add the original sender's email into the message via some sort of meta info and having MS Exchange recognize that. Is it possible? What other methods could I use even if it's outside of Exchange.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't that kinda defeat the standard purpose of "noreply@whatever.com"?  Seems to me it would be a better idea to create a separate mailbox that the user can send from.  If you add special headers to the original message then it becomes trivial for any malicious piece of garbage out there to track it back to the original sender.

Comment: Well ideally we don't want anyone replying, but sometimes people aren't too tech savvy and they're going to respond anyways. In an event like that we really want the email to get back to the original sender without having someone sort through the potential incoming emails and forwarding themselves. We'd also like to avoid creating alternative emails for the users because the additional inbox requirements would be in the thousands. It's really not a big deal if someone finds the hidden email in the headers, but we'd prefer that the average person doesn't have it handy. If possible.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.  Unfortunately I'm not an Exchange guru, though...  Wish I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am unaware of a method by which you can do this centrally from within Exchange, you could use the `Reply-To` header to suggest alternate delivery of a reply message.

To do so, you would setup a "noreplies" mailbox and grant the "Send As" permission to those users who need such an ability.  Then, in Outlook, select the "noreplies" mailbox as the "From" address, and specify the "Have replies sent to" option with the address of the actual user.

The "From" address line is hidden by default, you can [enable it in the ribbon](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/121).  The "Have replies sent to" option is under message options in 2003 and shows up in the ribbon as "Direct replies to" in 2007 and above.

Alternatively, if you require a non-interactive route, you could [write a mail transport agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa579074%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) to check the contents of the `From` header, and place the value of the `Return-Path` header, which contains the actual user who sent the message, in the `Reply-To` header.

If you really feel adventurous, you could write a transport agent which adds a `X-Noreplies-MessageID: SomeUniqueID` header, record the original sender and the unique ID in a database, and perform the opposite operation on receipt of a message directed to noreplies.

Comment: Okay the adventurous option is definitely the most ideal option and sounds pretty fun to work on. I'm glad this should be possible. I'll look into this at work tomorrow. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Dub, good man!